# QGIS add project variables using python code

Tags: variables, qgis

Is it possible to create/update project variables in QGIS through code?  We generate about 1000 small projects a year in my company - for each job, we copy a QGIS template.  Our goal is to use project variables within the QGIS project - but we'd like to pre-populate them when we copy the template.
Alternatively - if we stored all of our QGIS projects in Postgres, could we store/retrieve the project variables in the database? A project table, for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ProjectInstance = QgsProject.instance()

#Use this to set the Variable
QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable(ProjectInstance, 'myVariable','myValue')

#Use this to get the Variable
print(QgsExpressionContextUtils.projectScope(ProjectInstance).variable('myVariable'))
```